# how to get the cart items by triggering webhook when user adds the item to an cart, or is there any other possibilities?

Tags: javascript, node.js, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have tried with webhook, custom topic *action.woocommerce_add_to_cart*, webhook is triggered and received  data in  request body as
`body: {"action":"woocommerce_add_to_cart","arg":"1373b284bc381890049e92d324f56de0"}`

there is no idea about arg or documentation.